# Pentaho failing connection durring Job

Tags: mysql, pentaho, mysql-connector, pentaho-spoon, mysql-connect

Im importing data from Microsoft SQl database to MYSQl data base.
I created a seperate transformation for each table input so i couldnt control the order of the imports of each table. the transformations all work when i run them seperatly but when I try to run the Job with all of the transformations in them it fails with a sql connection error.

Because of an error, this step can't continue: 
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : Error performing rollback on connection
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : Communications link failure during rollback(). Transaction resolution unknown.
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : 
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.rollback(Database.java:739)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.rollback(Database.java:713)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableoutput.TableOutput.writeToTable(TableOutput.java:395)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableoutput.TableOutput.processRow(TableOutput.java:128)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:50)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: Communications link failure during rollback(). Transaction resolution unknown.
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:861)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.rollback(ConnectionImpl.java:4561)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.rollback(Database.java:728)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   ... 5 more
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : Unexpected error committing the database connection.
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : Unable to empty ps and commit connection.
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : No operations allowed after statement closed.
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : 
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.emptyAndCommit(Database.java:1523)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableoutput.TableOutput.dispose(TableOutput.java:658)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:79)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No operations allowed after statement closed.
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:965)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:861)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.checkClosed(StatementImpl.java:442)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.checkClosed(ServerPreparedStatement.java:510)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1228)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeBatch(StatementImpl.java:970)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.emptyAndCommit(Database.java:1486)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   ... 3 more
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - DELIVERY - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : Errors detected!
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : Unable to empty ps and commit connection.
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : No operations allowed after statement closed.
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : 
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.emptyAndCommit(Database.java:1523)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableoutput.TableOutput.dispose(TableOutput.java:658)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:79)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: No operations allowed after statement closed.
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:965)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:861)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.checkClosed(StatementImpl.java:442)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at com.mysql.jdbc.ServerPreparedStatement.checkClosed(ServerPreparedStatement.java:510)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeBatchInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1228)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeBatch(StatementImpl.java:970)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.emptyAndCommit(Database.java:1486)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   ... 3 more
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - DELIVERY - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : Errors detected!
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : Unexpected error rolling back the database connection.
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : Error performing rollback on connection
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : No operations allowed after connection closed.
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : 
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.rollback(Database.java:739)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.rollback(Database.java:713)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableoutput.TableOutput.dispose(TableOutput.java:708)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:79)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:919)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:898)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:887)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:861)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.throwConnectionClosedException(ConnectionImpl.java:1184)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.checkClosed(ConnectionImpl.java:1179)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.rollback(ConnectionImpl.java:4523)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.rollback(Database.java:728)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   ... 4 more
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 152 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 152 milliseconds ago.
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor57.newInstance(Unknown Source)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:990)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3749)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2512)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2683)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2482)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.rollbackNoChecks(ConnectionImpl.java:4657)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.rollback(ConnectionImpl.java:4549)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.rollback(Database.java:728)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at org.pentaho.di.core.database.Database.rollback(Database.java:713)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableoutput.TableOutput.writeToTable(TableOutput.java:395)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at org.pentaho.di.trans.steps.tableoutput.TableOutput.processRow(TableOutput.java:128)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at org.pentaho.di.trans.step.RunThread.run(RunThread.java:50)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   ... 1 more
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) : Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(Unknown Source)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.send(MysqlIO.java:3730)
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - ERROR (version 4.4.0-stable, build 17588 from 2012-11-21 16.02.21 by buildguy) :   ... 11 more
2018/07/06 19:47:23 - delivery 2.0 - Finished processing (I=0, O=20000, R=21000, W=20000, U=0, E=1)

Comment: Do you run the transformation in parallel ?

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the description I can say, You have to share the database connection which you have created in transformation or you have to create a database connection again at job level.